# Is it possible to upgrade MongoDB from 2.0 to 2.4 directly

Tags: mongodb

We have a replica set with 2 members and one arbiter in production. 10gen documentation states that 2.0 to 2.2 is a binary-compatible “drop-in" upgrade and so it's 2.2 to 2.4. 
Is it safe to upgrade from the 2.0 version directly to the 2.4 version?

Comment: Someone voted for closing this question. Is SO wrong place to ask this kind of questions? Should this question be moved to dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com?

Comment: 2 people seem to prefer this on dba.stackexchange.com, I personally am not sure; you might find better answers there

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Posted on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40889/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-mongodb-from-2-0-to-2-4-directly